# Play store Download to all devices?

Tags: google-play

I've configured an email ID (obviously gmail id) to **20 android devices** all are situated at different place now if i want to install an **application**. **to all device** like **Avast antivirus** 
if any device have already installed then how could i be able to do this.

**Goal :**

**1:** Install an application to all devices if not intalled.

**2:** devices may have already intstalled application then it will show install say if one have intall and other don't then how to install in all devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not too versed in telephony. I know for blackberries you have to have a  blackberry [enterprise] server to manage devices in this fashion. I think one client for android is called *Good*, but if you do a search for *android enterprise management*, you probably could find others.